# Help with question involving k-regular graphs

Tags: graphs

In my last test, our teacher gave us this question:

> In an conference with 90 participants, the staff wants to divide all
>   participants in 6 groups of 15 participants each. Each participant of
>   each group must have at least one article with exactly 7 other
>   participants of the same group. Prove using Graph Theory that this
>   division is impossible.

I spent a lot of time thinking about, but couldn't find an definitive answer. I think that this involve bipartite matching somehow, but I have no idea on how to proceed with the proof. I thought that maybe creating a k-regular graph would prove that this don't have a matching, but I couldn't come with the graph representing the problem.

Can I get some help with this?

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 7-regular graph on 15 vertices, since $7\times 15$ is odd.

Comment: Thank you! This is based on the handshaking lemma for graphs?

Comment: Exactly. That's the reason.